# R: identifying missing pdf files

Tags: r

I have a number of pdf files in the work directory that are identified by the vector

```
filespdf <- c("a.pdf","b.pdf","c.pdf","e.pdf","f.pdf"."g.pdf")
```

At times some of these pdf files may be missing in the working directory.
How can I identify which pdf files are missing from within R?

Thank you for any help or suggestions.

Comment: `?file.exists()`

Comment: Thank you every so much. That is extremely helpful.